# Human verification on fail to submit

Tags: bug, status-declined, captcha

When you can't submit the question for any reason (ie: must include tag), and you fix the issue and click "Ask your Question" again, you are prompted with the human verification captcha

Comment: You should stop correcting your mistakes with robot-like speed.

Comment: I only had one of the mandatory tags missing, it's not super hard to fix in 3 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Human Verification is just that. To confirm that you are a human and not a bot. Most automated process will continually post until they are successful. Ie. They will keep adding tags until the submission is accepted. This is the reason the Trilogy does not contain SPAM. Considering the irritation of spam on other forums and group I am more then happy with this.

This is not a bug, and I am extremely surprised Jeff didn't flag it by-design.

Comment: If I were hateful, I would call him Jeff "please-re-design" Atwood ♦

Comment: That is only one of the reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Annoying, but at least you don't loose your progress. Instead of skipping the CAPTCHA for this issue, why not have a javascript verification **before** the data gets sent to the server?

Answer (score 0):

This one bugs me too.  I'd suggest if the failure is just a lack of title or tags, that the system skip the CAPTCHA.