# Notification bar showing up long after bounty given

Tags: support, bounties, notification-bar

I had implemented a bounty on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/can-the-team-provide-some-explanation-for-declined-feature-requests), received the 24-hour notification bar yesterday, went to it and gave the bounty to an answer.

I was then on Meta for many hours.  This morning when I signed on, I received another 24-hour notification bar, but double-checking, my bounty had been given.

Comment: this has happened to me twice now (first documented on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57660/) and again with this comment; my consecutive SO days is 15 so I'm pretty sure I didn't miss the giant orange bar for the last several days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's by design -- all messages sit in your message queue until you view them.

Otherwise we couldn't "prove" that we did, indeed, notify you of the bounty expiration (twice even).

(caveats: we also do email reminders of bounties, assuming we have your email address -- we don't require email to participate here. Additionally, we do delete ancient messages after 4 months whether read or not.)

Comment: Is that 4 months after the first banner, or 4 months after the latest update? How long will I get to keep this `You've earned "Nice Question" and 3 other badges. See your profile.` banner going?

Comment: My point was that I had viewed the message, had been on all day afterwards, without a message, and then it popped up again this morning.

Comment: @lance never heard of that; you sure it wasn't the 2nd notification?

Comment: @lance and you're clicking the [x] to dismiss it?

Comment: I dismissed it either using the [x] or clicking on the link to go to the post itself, I can't remember which way I used.  If it was a 2nd notification, then that would be a bug, since the bounty would have already been awarded.  I tried to verify when I awarded the bounty, but the timeline view doesn't show it.  I'll post another feature request on that.