# "Your bounty will expire, uh, yesterday" notifications, despite visiting every day - is this really by-design?

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, notifications

### Abstract:

I've offered a bounty on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226880/secure-remote-api-in-app-engine-with-openid) on SO, but I only received the orange notification bars this morning, several days after the bounty has expired (visited SO every day, didn't get notification previously).

(A question similar to this one has been closed as "duplicate and by-design" - how is a notification "Note, this will happen yesterday" by design? The "[original](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58050/notification-bar-showing-up-long-after-bounty-given)" question seems to be different from the "duplicate".)

### What I did:

- offer bounty on question
- (get no answers)
- (visited site every day)
- let bounty expire on Tuesday, Sep 14th
- (visited site every day)

### What I expected to happen:

- get notification bar three days before bounty expires
- get e-mail and notification bar 24 hrs before bounty expires
- (if I don't choose an answer and there's no answer eligible for auto-bounty, bounty expires)

### What happened:

- on Monday, Sep 13th I received an e-mail (as expected) saying

> Received: from stackoverflow.com (unknown [10.0.0.5]) by
> mail1.stackoverflow.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 55CD41E08B; Mon, 13 Sep 2010
> 01:44:29 -0700 (PDT)
>
> (...)
>
> Your bounty on the question
> Secure remote_api in app engine with OpenID
> ends in 23 hours."

- bounty expired on Tuesday, Sep 14th
- on Thursday, Sep 16th, around 9:00 CEST (which should be around 00:00 PDT), I got two orange bars saying "Your bounty ... expires (in 24 hours|within three days)", respectively ([see screenshot](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/3319/latenotification.png))

### My usage patterns:

Between the time when I've offered the bounty and its expiration, I have been visiting SO every day ([currently 32 days in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19746/piskvor)) and I estimate that I see at least 20 pages each day (many more on some days). **Other notifications show up correctly** (favorites, replies, comments, badges), and I dismiss them using the "x" button on the right.

### Similar questions:

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58050/notification-bar-showing-up-long-after-bounty-given/58060#58060) to a similar question *seems* to say it is by design; but IMO this is a different case: for me, both the notification bars showed up at the same time, I have *not* seen them previously, and I doubt I would miss a huge orange bar across the screen, much less two of them.

There is at least [one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57660/24-hr-bounty-alert-came-many-days-too-late-closed) here that has been closed as duplicate, referring to Jeff's answer as "by-design". In my opinion, those are not duplicates, as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58050/notification-bar-showing-up-long-after-bounty-given) seems to be "didn't click the close-notification button the first time, and thus correctly got the notification again", whereas the [not-exact-duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57660/24-hr-bounty-alert-came-many-days-too-late-closed) and this question are "did not get the notification bar *at all* before bounty expired."

**If this behavior is really by-design, what purpose is there for a notification saying "you should do something yesterday"?**

Comment: I can confirm this. The orange bars appeared some days after I accepted the bounty. (Which I did with only some hours left.)

Comment: +1 I had a similar thing on the cooking.se site where  I recently (yesterday I think) got three notifications at the same time about various thingsm, but one of them was an outdated notification about a bounty I had awarded ending in 3 days/24 hours, when actually it was ending on that day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this, completely by coincidence, as I had opened a bounty on someone else's question.

This would only happen if **you, too, had opened a bounty on someone else's question**.

Now fixed though.

Comment: I forgot to mention that in the question - it was indeed a bounty on someone else's question. Thanks a lot!