# Bounties not listed in timeline

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, timeline

When you go to the timeline view of a question, [like this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/6959/timeline), it doesn’t show any bounty activity. The [regular view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11937/131979) does show if a bounty was awarded, but if it expired, there is no user-visible trace.

Comment: Related, but for general revision history instead of timeline view: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history.

Comment: This would be really cool. And [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229210/full-or-partial-refund-of-expired-bounty-in-certain-very-rare-scenarios) gave me the idea of adding the number of views when the bounty starts and finishes. This way, the user will have an idea of how many views s/he *buyed*.

Comment: let's have it together with the message that was given by the user offering the bounty. Otherwise, valuable information is lost when the bounty finishes! Starting a meta-bounty on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new timeline released, all bounty information is now visible in the timeline. E.g. [this very question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/58072/timeline)