# Show what answers existed before a bounty?

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties, user-interface, unanswered-questions

I have just start looking at bounty questions and I don't know if some answers existed before posting the bounty. Maybe the OP is busy and someone has already answer the question he was asking and there is no point in me answering.

P.S. I could calculate the time in what the answers were posted, but first I would have to read bounty FAQ to see how long bounty last. In stackoverflow era nobody is reading any manual. Most user won't waste time calculating the time and will just ignore the question as I am doing right now.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be nice if [the timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4623193/timeline) showed the bounty event, just like the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/4623193/revisions) already does. For that, vote on [Timeline view doesn't show bounty award](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58072/timeline-view-doesnt-show-bounty-award).

Comment: I think we need a Time Machine for this…

Comment: so you can implement it? ;)

Comment: This would help in cases where people think they should have been auto-awarded the bounty only to find that their answer predates the bounty and is therefore not eligible for auto acceptance.