# Add a way to see previous bounties and their reasons for any question

Tags: feature-request, bounties

We now have the ability to offer bounties with custom messages, which is great and extremely useful. It allows the person offering a bounty to state specifically what they're looking for.

[image: Example One]
[image: Example Two]

However once the bounty is awarded there seems to be no way to view the reasons for the bounty anymore. Can this be added? It would be useful in showing why the accepted answer deserved the bounty.

Comment: Also, related but not a dupe: [Timeline view doesn't show bounty award](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58072/131541)

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought it would have been visible in the revision history.

Comment: So would I @Jeff! [Yet it wasn't](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/90620/revisions)

Comment: +1, but this is essentially a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history

Comment: @Nemo except my question predates that one by 3 days, so *that* question is a dupe of *this* one ;-)