# Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history

Tags: feature-request, bounties, revisions-list, bounty-remarks

A question's revision history has shown bounty events [for quite some time now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history/67747#67747). Since then, Stack Exchange has also added support for [bounty remarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103956/162705).

I would like to request that bounty remarks be added to the revision history, as well.

For example, consider [the revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/83292/revisions) for [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83292/detail-recent-favorite-changes).

> [image: Revision history screenshot]

This may be more prevalent on Meta SO than other sites, but when there are multiple bounties on a single question I think that it would be helpful to have a history of the bounty remarks to clarify precisely why the bounty was offered, rather than a series of "Authoritative reference needed" notices.

Comment: I would also really love to see a caption "This question had a bounty of N, but it expired" or such on questions.

Comment: @sindikat Do you mean a caption when a bounty expires without having *any* answers automatically awarded? As shown in [this revision history](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/83292/revisions), there *is* a notice whenever Community♦ automatically awards a bounty.

Comment: Yep, you are right, i mean the bounties, that were never awarded. I just wanted to see mentions of previous bounties on the same page, so everyone will see, that this question received someone's attention, enough for him to start a bounty. It's a pity to lose 50 points with the only mention in revision history :)

Comment: when would community give out bounties automatically

Comment: @HBellamy In this case Community♦ is only mentioned in the revision history because no one was awarded the bounty. As far as I know, Community♦ does not give out bounties.

Comment: this very [question history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/110003/revisions) currently shows five bounties. Quite a pity that one can't see their remarks

Comment: It would also be nice to see bounty comments in the mouse-over text for an awarded bounty on an answer, I think.

Comment: I have a feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252633/in-the-posthistory-table-what-is-that-number-in-the-comment-column) to get the text of the notices in SEDE

Comment: What? From when does Community award bounties? Community has 1 rep point, how can he do bounties??? (Yes last year I was on SE, but not in 2011, then I was too young to use internet networks at all)

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I'm pretty sure that [Community♦ owns bounties from deleted users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19739/162705).

Comment: @ChrisFrederick So it wasn't *awarded* by Community. Thanks for the hidden tip.

Comment: @EKons Community owns auto-awarded bounties (the ones that are awarded for half value if the bounty-giver doesn't choose an answer).

Answer (score 20):

It is not yet added to the revision history but my earlier [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278150/158100) to add this data to [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) has been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

So until this gets added to the revision history you can now run [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/631856?questionid=83292)

```sql
select pn.body as [Custom Comment]
     , pt.Name as [Notice Type]
     , pt.Body as [Reason]
     , pn.creationdate
     , pn.deletiondate
     , owneruserid as [User Link]
from postnotices pn
inner join postnoticetypes pt on pt.id = pn.postnoticetypeid
where postid = ##questionid?83292##
```

To find the bounty remarks for a question. For the question you used as an example this is what the result looks like at the time of posting:

> [image: result of post notices]

Keep in mind that SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday.