# Editing bounty text

Tags: feature-request, bounty-remarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text)

When I start a bounty I have to select the reason of doing so from a category and then I am allowed to enter free text. There is no opportunity to edit this text afterwards.

Comment: So you want to offer a bounty to one specific person.  [John Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) **will** answer your question even if its not a bounty.  If you ask Skeet will come...

Comment: So if someone starts working on a rather work intensive task to get the bounty, then returns after completion only to see that your requirements have changed in the meantime just because you didn't think before posting (since it can always be edited), that'd be acceptable for you?

Comment: No I will be glad if anyone answers my question. But whats the problem to draw someones attention to a question? The part you are refering was just an addon, I will remove that. The question is about editing the text.

Comment: In my opinion the question itself should state the requirement. The add-on text just shows the reason why I set up a bounty. If you have a misspelling or in my case would like to remove the not working mention of a specific person I have no chance to do so.

Comment: Bounties are a good way to raise attention to other peoples' issues you might also have or want an answer to. In these cases, editing the original post isn't always a good way to properly convey your own, possible slightly differing requirements. Also, something that enables you to fix a typo will also allow you to completely change the entire description unless there is some kind of approval process.

Comment: What about having the same mechanism as with comments - just allow editing a certain time range?

Comment: Related question? **[Can we have a way to edit bounty text?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text)**

Answer (score 1):

I've thought about this feature request for a while myself, and have had a hard time figuring out whether it would be worth the cost of implementation. I can only think of two reasons that I would choose to edit a bounty remark.

1. To fix spelling, grammar, formatting, and other typographical mistakes
2. To clarify meaning

Of course, the ability to edit bounty remarks could also be *abused* for a number of reasons.

1. To entirely change the remark text
2. To carry on a conversation with people in comments on the original question

These would be really annoying to deal with.

Nevertheless, were it possible to edit bounty remarks, another concern is whether those revisions should be tracked. If they aren't, you can be certain that sooner or later someone on Meta is going to request revision tracking for bounty remarks. In other words, your feature request would beget more, which quickly becomes a slippery slope. Besides, bounty remarks aren't even saved in a question's revision history (though [I would argue that they should](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history)). In short, implementing this request would raise a host of other issues—*all for the sake of editing text that's only going to be visible for a week, anyway.*

If bounty remarks are ever saved in a question's revision history, well. . .this may be worth revisiting.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From a product owners point of view you are absolutely right and I accept the current behaviour. From the users point of view I learned from setting my first bounty that I will never use this field in future anymore - since it is optional, this is ok.