# Should moderators be able to edit Bounty text?

Tags: discussion

Moderators can edit questions, answers and comments, but apparently not Bounty text.

- Why is this the case?
- Should it remain this way?

There is already [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112188/can-we-have-a-way-to-edit-bounty-text) about user edits of bounty text, but not one regarding moderator edits that I can find.

Comment: If something *bad* happens (like abuse), I can just refund the bounty (and suspend the user, as needed).    The OP can always clarify, in a comment or the question, if the bounty text is somehow insufficient.

Comment: Since the bounty text is not retained after the bounty period, I don't see a pressing need for there to be an edit feature and as Robert says, if something bad happens, you can always refund the bounty. A better case could be made for retaining the bounty text in the post history (except when it is refunded)... Often times, I'm clueless as to why the OP placed a bounty, but didn't award it — did they not like the answers? Were the answers off-target? Did they just not come back?.

Comment: Considering the huge rep cost needed to place a bounty, I'm surprised the *user* can't edit its text.

Comment: Related to yoda's comment: [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110003)

Comment: @NullUser I assume that it to avoid the bounty becoming a moving target.  Hopefully moderators would know better.

Answer (score 1):

Users should be careful when writing their bounty messages. A single typo might be embarrasing, but it won't have any lasting effect. Editing is a task that doesn't scale well to the moderator level, on sites like SO there are so few mods compared to the number of users that you really don't want to burden the mods with additional tasks. So I don't think it makes sense to allow mods to edit the bounty message.

To deal with malicious or abusive bounty messages the mods can just refund the bounty and suspend the user, if necessary. That should be enough.

There might be a case for a grace period in which the original user can edit his bounty message, to correct any mistake.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the "SO is so large that things don't scale, so let's kill this idea that will be useful on the rest of the 90 other sites" approach to discuss feature requests. I do agree that moderators need not be given special rights to edit them (the bounty text is an edge case that it doesn't seem necessary)... simply having a 5 min grace window should be sufficient (just like you and only you can change the edit reason within the grace period as long as an incremental minor change accompanies it)

Comment: @yoda It's more that I think that editing is fundamentally something the community needs to do, delegatin that to the mods breaks down long before reaching SO levels of traffic. And as a mod I also don't want the power to edit anything that doesn't have a revision history.

Comment: As I said, I couldn't care less about it being a mod only privilege (I'd rather users be allowed to edit it themselves), but I don't think it would break down or lead to chaos like you seem to portray. Mods can edit comments too, and those don't have revision history either. I haven't seen SO mods complaining about being drowned in flags requesting comments to be edited.