# How can I view the remarks on an old bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, bounty-remarks

How can I view the remarks on an old bounty?

I could swear I knew how to do this at one point, but the bounty remark text doesn't seem to be available at `/posts/.../timeline` or `/posts/.../revisions`, nor is it in the PostHistory or Votes table on SEDE.

Comment: Never been possible it looks like: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110003/add-bounty-remarks-to-a-questions-revision-history

Comment: senshin you have a choice: if you mean this to be feature request then it's a duplicate (can be closed, no harm done) or you can also keep it just a support question and maybe get answer explaining the reason behind the decision not to add the remarks to revisions.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Ah, bugger. I even have that feature request favorited! I must be going senile. Anyway, yeah, I voted to close as a dupe of the link random posted.

Comment: @random if it's just "is this possible and if not, why not?" then it's not a duplicate in my opinion

Comment: @senshin you can now have a binding close vote, reload and click the button. :)

Comment: @random ie. duplicate to the feature request of your dupe..

Comment: @ShadowWizard Whaaaaaat. I get to dupehammer my own questions now?! This is awesome!

Comment: Oh, you don't want it? Gimme it, gimme it!!! :P