# Should answers with bounty-awards get flagged for deletion?

Tags: discussion, bounties, flags

I stumbled upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8254796/331508), which currently reads (not counting the screenshot):

> Well here is the screenshot for it, there is htmleditor in radgrid and
>   this time i got this screen. Can't write anything in it because there
>   is no line. I have this problem on development and live server.
>
> {[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHhfl.jpg)}
>
> So what can i do for it?

My first instinct is to flag this post for deletion as "Not an answer", but then [smartcaveman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344211/smartcaveman?tab=reputation) awarded it a 50-point bounty!

Was this just an accident or is there some kind of code, or something else, I missed?

Should this answer be flagged as "Not an answer", even though it has a bounty award?

Comment: I'm giving him a chance to reply to your comment before deleting that answer.

Comment: You know, if we could [see pervious bounties and their reasons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109747/add-a-way-to-see-previous-bounties-and-their-reasons-for-any-question) we might know why smartcaveman offered / awarded that bounty... ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should this answer be flagged as "Not an answer", even though it has a bounty award?

Absolutely. It may  need to be integrated into the question, or deleted - it's not an answer at any rate.

I have no idea why somebody would award a bounty to that..... Maybe there was previous history (like the OP writing a great answer on one of smartcaveman's questions but not getting a bounty for some reason, and smartcaveman looking to award him 50 points without checking whether the contribution actually made sense).

Comment: On second look, I'm not *sure* whether it can be integrated into the question. I'll leave it for now.

Comment: Why can't (couldn't) it be integrated?  I pasted the information into the question as it does seem to belong there.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to find [through Google's cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:stackoverflow.com/questions/8081618/telerik-radeditor-doesnt-work-well-on-live-website) the bounty reason:

> ### This question has an open [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) worth +50 reputation from [smartcaveman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344211/smartcaveman) ending in 5 days.
>
> This question has not received enough attention.
>
> I am having this issue as well. Everything works perfectly on our development site, but the live site RadEditor is busted. This seems very strange.

I have no idea why smartcaveman awarded the bounty where he did. Maybe he figured out his problem from the screencapture? Very odd.

I'd say merge the answer with the question. It's not an answer and isn't worth +50 rep. (What will happen to the rep? It will be lost on a recalc probably... but does smartcaveman get it back..? Apparently for a question to be deleted, [a diamond must refund the bounty first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47470/131541)... what about answers though?)

Comment: +1, nice research. <strike>Pretty sure, from the FAQ, that smartcaveman doesn't get it back.</strike>

Comment: Thanks @Brock. Actually he would have to. To delete that answer [the bounty must first be refunded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47470/131541)

Comment: Actually, in a round-about way, this bounty award *did* draw attention. :)

Comment: That is very true @Brock!

Comment: That bit about refunding the bounty applies to **questions**.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47470), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16067), and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27103).  No mention is made of how **answers** are handled. ... ... In fact it would be diabolical if the rep was refunded.  I could get traffic on my Q, then award the bounty to an NAA (generated by my sock-puppet, if necessary).  Then the answer gets flagged and ka-ching!

Comment: Very good point @BrockAdams. I updated my answer...  [and asked my own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113707)

Comment: Thanks again for the clues as to why the bounty was awarded, but the most-correct answer seems to be "Flag with extreme prejudice". :)