# What happens if an answer which was awarded a bounty is merged or deleted?

Tags: support, bounties, deleted-answers

Inspired by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113697), what happens if:

1. User #1 posts a question.
2. User #2 offers a bounty on said question
3. User #3 answers the question with a horrible, terrible answer
4. User #2 awards the bounty to the terrible answer because they're confused or they're trying to confuse the rest of us
5. The terrible answer is flagged and a mod:

   1. Deletes the answer altogether. (Can they do this?)
   2. Converts the answer to a comment or to it's own question.

**This is not a duplicate of [If a bounty question is deleted after awarding it, what happens?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47401/if-a-bounty-question-is-deleted-after-awarding-it-what-happens/47470#47470) because mine is about a deleted *answer*.**

Does the bounty have to be refunded first? What happens to the rep? Isn't this a possible form of gaming? See [Brock's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113697/should-answers-with-bounty-awards-get-flagged-for-deletion/113704#comment-295414):

> That bit about refunding the bounty applies to **questions**. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47470), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16067), and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27103). No mention is made of how **answers** are handled. ... ... In fact it would be diabolical if the rep was refunded. I could get traffic on my Q, then award the bounty to an NAA (generated by my sock-puppet, if necessary). Then the answer gets flagged and ka-ching!

Comment: I'll offer a bounty on this question in two days to test... if we don't have a definite answer by then ;-)

Comment: Wait, no, *I* can't offer the bounty. Someone else needs to. Maybe my sockpuppet can help me here....

Comment: I'll volunteer for posting the bounty if there is no conclusive answer - might need to ping me though, not sure I'll remember :)

Answer (score 2):

One of my answers with a bounty was deleted off late, so here's my understanding:

> Deletes the answer altogether. (Can they do this?)

Yes, Mods can delete answers with bounty already assigned.

> Does the bounty have to be refunded first? What happens to the rep? Isn't this a possible form of gaming?

The bounty isn't refunded - and like most situations involving a delete, the rep will be reallocated to he community user and not refunded to the person putting the bounty.

The person who *won* the bounty, however loses rep and this will be corrected whenever the next rep recalc is done.

---

**Case study:** Bounty on a question which is now offtopic & closed.

Starting rep(rep was recalc'd before starting this study to negate any other effects):

- OP: 739
- Answerer: 14,636

---

[image: deleted post with 100 rep bounty, 3 upvotes, accepted answer]

So - the rep should be 14,636 - 100 - 30 - 15 = 14,491

> Recalculated rep for User.Id -> old rep = 14636, new rep = 14491

As for the OP:

> Recalculated rep for User.Id -> old rep = 739, new rep = 737

(2 rep drop since the accepted answer is also lost).

Comment: Is there any mention in /reputation at all? And did this indeed get deleted by a moderator?

Comment: Yes, this was deleted by a moderator(read me :P ) @Arjan

Comment: Hmmm, hence self-deletion, in a way?

Comment: The question is now deleted, and deleting the question refunds the bounty @BrockAdams. If the question isn't deleted, the rep listing shows bounty deduction

Comment: @Arjan It wasn't self deletion, [this is the question](http://superuser.com/questions/81637/alerts-for-google-tasks)