# Can I get the exact time when an accept happened or a bounty started?

Tags: support, bounties

In one of the questions the OP added a bounty and accepted my answer. The bounty is awarded only if the accept happened after the addition of bounty. How do I know the order these events happened if I can see only the result that there is a bounty and my accepted question?

On other words, how can I get the exact date and time the bounty started and the acception happened. Is this possible through the StackExchange API?

Comment: You will get more help if you post a link to the question.

Comment: I updated the question to emphasize the requested info. According to this, I'd say this is not a duplicate. I posted because the referred post doesn't contain this info.

Comment: @allprog I don't think updates after the start of the bounty count for the automatic awarding. The OP will have to award it to you explicitly.

Comment: Your question finishes with "*through the API*". Do you really mean that? Is this a question about the stack exchange API or the web interface?

Comment: I'm asking about the StackExchange API.

Comment: @allprog If you only want to know how to get the exact time for an acceptance through the API, then please have your title reflect that. Your title and question don't match otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the exact time when a question has been accepted by hovering over the Accepted checkmark.

If you need a more fine grained control, you can check the **[question's timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18331331/timeline)**, which indicates the accept happened exactly on 08:56:15, while the bounty was started on 08:55:39.

Which means he accepted your answer after the bounty has been started.

Comment: 2 hours ago is too big granularity. It's exactly the same for the bounty. The question is not decidable this way. Is it possible to get the milliseconds, or something more fine grained value?

Comment: Not sure, can you provide a link to the question?

Comment: Great, I can't see the bounty in the timeline but I trust your observation . :)

Comment: The timeline does indeed not show bounties: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58072/timeline-view-doesnt-show-bounty-award

Comment: @allprog: The bounty can be seen when hovering over the "Ends in 7 days" in the question itself. It's not found in the timeline AFAICT.

Comment: Yes, I realized in the mean time. Swift answer. :)

Comment: @allprog: "*Is it possible to get the milliseconds*" Milliseconds? Why would you *ever* need that level of precision? Are you stalking someone?

Comment: Sure not. But there needs to be a unit of time for stack overflow events. As I saw in the API, this is milliseconds. So I asked for it. I cannot reliably compare two times that are precise to the minute or hour if events can happen in the order of seconds or milliseconds.