# Add an explanation for status-declined

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tags

Just as for the duplicate, we should add a reason, on top of the post, as for why the feature request was declined.

Feature requests are a very important part of the site but so is the response from the team. Sometimes, [it's hard to see why the proposal was rejected](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags) in the lot of answers and still it's just a guess by trying to find the staff in all the users that posted.

It would be way easier if something like this was done :

> [image]

Comment: Usually an answer is posted where it's not obvious, but I can see the usefulness of this

Comment: This feature request retagged with [tag:status-declined] and no explanation in 3...2...1...

Comment: @Ai I almost asked please don't close this as status declined just for the irony.

Comment: It took me all of 3 seconds to find the staff answer to the linked question.  The diamonds tend to stand out if you're specifically looking for them.  I really don't see this as a major problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73857/require-a-one-sentence-explanation-for-status-declined-if-the-request-has-20-up http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113708/can-moderators-leave-a-note-when-things-are-by-design-or-declined

Comment: @Servy Good thing this isn't tagged as a major problem then.